# How to change picture in a telegram bot message?

Tags: java, telegram, telegram-bot

I have a telegram bot, to create used library [TelegramBots](https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots)

Bot show post with text and image. The post looks like this:

[image]

When you press the inline buttons text of post changed (I used for this [EditMessageCaption](https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots/blob/b3828accbe0a6941491ede4d0bac1d46d0750c60/telegrambots-meta/src/main/java/org/telegram/telegrambots/api/methods/updatingmessages/EditMessageCaption.java)) , but I can not change the picture.

Does anyone know how to change the picture of message with image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, the picture can not be changed, but you can just paste the url into the text and change it.